# Windows Server 2008 R2: perl ppm doesn't see modules unless I'm the system administrator

Tags: windows, perl

I just did a fresh install of ActiveState Perl 5.16.3 on a Windows Server 2008 R2 system, and things seemed to go OK until I went to review the installed modules with Perl Package Manager (PPM).

When run as myself, no packages appeared when "View Installed Modules" is enabled.  However, when I right-click and choose "Run as administrator", then a list of 276 installed modules is displayed.

What's causing the difference in what PPM shows a user?  The folder C:\Perl has read access for the Users group.  Is there a PPM database file that has special access permissions?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue today and it had to do with no (valid) perl binary in the PATH environment for the user calling ppm. Try setting it for the user that has the problem.

(Late answer, maybe it helps someone in the future)